# how to delete the subset from array?

Tags: c++, c++11

i had find all the subset of size k of given array with distinct elements.

i want to delete the subset from a generated subset that i got from the array.

how to remove the subset from all subset that is generated.

just give the idea to solve this type of problem.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int n, int r, int index, int data[], int i); 

void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r) 
{ 
    int data[r]; 

    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, 0, data, 0); 
} 

void combinationUtil(int arr[], int n, int r, int index, 
                    int data[], int i) 
{ 
    if (index == r) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) 
            printf("%d ", data[j]); 
        printf("\n"); 
        return; 
    } 
    if (i >= n) 
        return; 
    data[index] = arr[i]; 
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index + 1, data, i + 1); 

    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index, data, i + 1); 
} 

int main() 
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m; 
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i]=i;
    }
    printCombination(arr, n, m);

    return 0; 
} 

if input is 0 1 2 3 4
and output is
0 1 
0 2 
0 3 
0 4 
1 2 
1 3 
1 4 
2 3 
2 4 
3 4
```

if i want to remove subset 0 2 and 2 3 how to solve this

Comment: Any reasons for not using `std::vector`?

Comment: `int data[r];` is not valid C++ (only  valid C), though some compilers support it as *extension* (thus is not portable!).

Comment: @Aconcagua in vector will it be easy

Comment: @Aconcagua then how to solve this

Comment: How can input be `0 1 2 3 4` if you only read two values (`n` and `m`)? If I understand your question correctly, you'd have input 5 and 2 to get printed output, wouldn't you?

Comment: n is the size of array where array always start from 0 and end upto n and m is size of subset to be generated

Comment: Why would you want to remove 0, 2 and 2, 3 exactly? What are the criteria for those to be removed?

Comment: i want to know how to remove the subset after getting the distinct subset if i want to remove (0,2) from the distinct subset how to solve this

Comment: You won't remove, you just will skip printing, as you actually never generate all sets. But do you have any criteria for specific numbers? Which sets would you select, if input was 5, 3? Some general critera for selecting the sets to skip, something like "I want to print all numbers, but exclude those that are not prime".

Comment: got it okay if input is n=5 m=3 and i have to remove m subset like (1,2),(3,4),(0,4) from generated subset

Comment: That doesn't make sense. With m = 3, your sets should contain three numbers, shouldn't they? Thus (1, 2, 3), ...

Comment: Just a totally general answer: You print the array as soon as last position is filled in, that's fine, but before actually printing, you'd need to check if the set stored in the array meets the desired criteria (whichever they are...), e. g. `if(index == r) { int sum = 0; for(int j = 0; j < r; ++j) { sum += data[j]; } if(sum == 10 || sum == 12) { for(int j = 0; j < r; ++j) { printf("%d ", data[j]); } }` would print only those sets which sum up to either 10 or 12...

Comment: see if n= 5 and m=3 then n size array will be {0,1,2,3,4} and we have to generate of subset of size 2  the generated subset 0 1 
0 2 
0 3 
0 4 
1 2 
1 3 
1 4 
2 3 
2 4 
3 4 and m is the subset which we have to remove {0,1},{1,2},{2,3}

Comment: Citing yourself: *'m is size of subset[s?] to be generated'* – your own code generates appropriate subsets, i. e. for m = 3 it generates 012, 013, 014, 023, ... You are providing contradictory information!

Comment: Just guessing: Could it be that you would remove for n=5 and m=3 subsets 012, 123, 234? That would be of each group of subsets with same smallest number the one with lowest sum. As your algorithm produces the subsets sorted, you'd need to skip a new subset as soon as very first number in data array changes...